# converting access mde from 32 bit to 64 bit

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I need to convert a 32 bit mde file to 64 bit mde. I am currently using Microsoft access for office 365 MSO 64 bit. The access database that I had was created in 32 bit. When I tried to open the access database, I got an error saying "This database was created with the 32-bit version of Microsoft access" . I tried to go to create a blank database on my 64 bit access and went to external data tab and with new data source, I tried to select my 32 bit version data, but I got the error again saying  "This database was created with the 32-bit version of Microsoft access"

I am not sure how can I convert this existing database to 64 bit.

Any help in this regards will be highly appreciated. I imported the tables like suggested below to a new accdb database, bute when I came to Forms , reports , Macros and modules tab, they are all disabled. I can only select Tables and queries from import objects menu. below is the screen shot of the tables, I can select all the tables:

[image]

below are the screen shot of Modules and forms. They are disabled. How can I import them too.

[image]

[image]

Thank you

Comment: I usually don't post web search suggestions since they appear to be lazy answers and I assume that you've already done research.  However, a simple search of `mde 64-bit` returns numerous discussion pages on other website that have potentially useful information.  It's not that they have a definitive answer from what I could find, but they contain various pieces of advice that cannot be summarize here.

Comment: Did you try any of them. Most of those searches don't work. I did the web search before posting my question.

Comment: Yes, and I read various comments about 32-bit vs 64-bit office, mde files, conversion, avoiding 64-bit office, etc.  I just clicked on the first 6 links and every one of them opened to a discussion, some on MS forums, some on UtterAccess, one on Experts Exchange.  I'm not sure where you're located, but keep in mind I'm seeing English results in the US.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot convert an `mde`!

You need the original `mdb` that was used as source to create the `mde`. You can compile the `mdb` to either a `32-bit mde` with a `32-bit` Access or to `64-bit mde` with a `64-bit` Access.

Comment: I got the .mdb file of this same database. I tried to convert it using External Data->New Data source->Access and tried to open my .mdb file and got the same 32 bit error. How can i convert the mdb file to 64 bit. I am not sure how to compile the mdb file. I cannot even open the file in 64 bit.

Comment: I am very new to access.

Comment: Two things you can try. 1. Open the mdb while holding the `Shift`-key so that no code starts running. 2. [Decompile](http://www.datagnostics.com/dtips/decompile.html) the mdb.

Comment: I am not sure what am I doing wrong. I tried to do every single step that is mentioned in the article that you gave me, but keep getting that 32 bit error then I tried to open the database in windows 7 machine and saw that the File->  save as button is also missing in this database. I am not  sure what is wrong about this database. Is thier any way, I can share the database with you. I don't want to post the database publicly.

Comment: If the database contains an AutoExec macro, this code will immediately start to run when you open the mdb, also the application might replace Access menus by application specifc menus and toolbars and special db properties might be applied. So make sure to open it by keeping the `Shift`-key pressed until the db is totally open! Also see [Bypass startup options when you open a database](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/bypass-startup-options-when-you-open-a-database-ba66917a-68b6-4fe6-8c23-33042953a5f9).

Comment: I held down the shift key and tried to open the database. still same 32 bit error and this error comes up while I am holding the shift key. I can open the same database in 32 bit version, but not in 64 bit. I also tried de compiling the access and tried to open the database. still same issue.

Comment: I never worked with a 64-Access, so cannot really tell you. Sorry.

Comment: mdb is the old Access format.  The newer format has an extension accdb (Access 2007 and later).  I'm not expert on the evolution of 64-bit Access, but I don't think the 64-bit version existed prior to the new standard format .  I suspect that if you are ever going to get this to work, that you'd need to convert the original mdb database to an accdb, and as I recall you likely need an older version of Access to do the conversion.  I'm not familiar with Office 365 version, but I though they removed conversion capability a few versions ago.

Comment: You should be able to open the mdb - you  may not be using the shift key hold down correctly. Just create a blank new accDB - and then import everything from the old database.

Comment: I created a new blank database and imported everything excepts forms and modules. Please see the screen shot in my original post. How can I import them?

Comment: Since you are able to open the MDB in 32-bit Access, do that and then save your forms, reports, and macros as text files using `Application.SaveAsText`. Then use 64-bit Access to open the new ACCDB which contains the imported tables and load those objects from the text files using `Application.LoadFromText`  Test first with one or a few of those objects.  If successful, do the same for the rest.